# How to display values from a database in 3 columns

Tags: python, html, css, django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjAeh.png)

Hello World, i need your help!

I try to find how to display data in 3 columns.( like at picture )
I work in django-framework.
Right now i have 1 column.
I have:

```
index.html
{% block content %}


{% for post in posts %}

  {% include 'face/includes/post_card_template.html' %}

{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

---

```
post_card_template.html

<h1 class='mb-5'> </h1>
   <div class="card mb-3" style="width:400px; border-radius: 8px; " >
   {% if post.image %}
       <img src="{{ post.image.thumbnail.400x400 }}" class="img-responsive"  style="border-radius: 8px;" alt="Card image" font-size:8px ;>
   {% endif %}
     <div class="card-body">
  <h4 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h4>
  <p class="card-text">{{ post.body1 }}</p>
  <p class="card-text">{{ post.body2 }}</p>
  <p class="card-text">{{ post.body3 }}</p>
  <p class="card-text">{{ post.body4 }}</p>
  <p class="card-text">{{ post.body5 }}</p>
  <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-secondary">Read</a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with bootstrap very easily

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" >.col-xs-4 .col-sm-4 .col-lg-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" >.col-xs-4 .col-sm-4 .col-lg-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" >.col-xs-4 .col-sm-4 .col-lg-4</div>
  </div>
```

Check full article: [Bootstrap grid examples](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp)

Comment: Lasha Pareshishvili, Good day! it's not exactly what I'm looking for, as you saw the project is made on jango.

Comment: Somebody help me?